# Setting up a unique Tag ID for Imageview in Android

Tags: java, android, uiimageview, tags

Hi I am trying to set up a tag id for a Image view in Android, I am creating an Image View dynamically where I will have multiple duplicate Imageviews but I want to have unique tag ids for each of them.

```
                final GWave tagger = new GWave();
                tagger.setSettagname("gulloo");
                tagger.setTagint(t);


                int id = getResources().getIdentifier("lock", "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
                final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                imageView.setX(t+100);

                imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.v("NAS", "hey im the new image view");
                    imageView.setTag(tagger);
                    Log.v("NAS", "My tag is " + String.valueOf(imageView.getTag()));

                    }
                });
```

Im getting the following output

```
 My tag is com.n4z.zwave.GWave@41c79f98
```

Any suggestions how I can fix this thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a tag that's an object. You're then calling `String.valueOf(....)`, which calls the `toString()` method of the object. If you want to customize this output, then you need to override `toString()` inside your `GWave` class.

```
public class GWave
{
  ....

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
     return "My Object: " + this.id; // Append String information to this to customize the output of toString
  }

}
```